# How to clear user data upon app update?

Tags: android

What I originally had: a launcher activity with a button which would launch my main activity. The launcher activity had shared preferences so it would only show up once. However, I have added a new activity that when the user clicks the button on the launcher activity, a introduction page is to appear. However due to shared preferences on my launcher activity, that introduction page does not show up.

So is there any way to clear the user's data on update? Just for this update,  When a user updates my app, I want this to run:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("cda-preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    settings.edit().clear().commit();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define a `BroadcastReceiver` for the `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` action. In this receiver's `onReceive` method you should clear the flag in the shared Preferences. (API12+)

```
<receiver
    android:name=".OnUpgradeReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Or you should save the version of your app (to the shared prefs). When the user launches the app you should check what was the previous one and if its newer, show the introduction page.

Comment: thanks. I used int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE; to solve my question